# How can i calculate the total percentage change in a portfolio(assume 100 buy in)if i have a list which shows each percentage change of each trade?

Tags: python, finance, portfolio

I am using the following code but I am missing something

```
percentagechange = [-2.704974336321264, -9.75579724548381, 161.1083287764476, -2.3049580623481725, -3.2221603096622586, -2.03531529638451, -6.491786990447023, 6.232016977803179, 25.025643012929887, 8.469894128276412, -5.697378424452704, 165.4820717201802]

totalreturns = [1]

for i in percentagechange:
    totalreturns = total_returns * ((i / 100) + 1)
```

I tried the above code but I can't get my head around the calculation. Please help.

Comment: Is your percentage change for a single asset at different time steps or for different assets in a portfolio? Suggest you start with something easy, like `[100, -50]` and see if you end up where you started.

Answer (score 0):

Percentege of change is defined as [ % Increase = Increase / Original Number × 100 ]

your code has a syntax error, totalreturns inside the loop is called totalreturns but also total_returns which is not defined.

But also following the formula (if I understood correctly) you would want to have something like:

```
percentagechange = [-2.704974336321264, -9.75579724548381, 161.1083287764476, -2.3049580623481725, -3.2221603096622586, -2.03531529638451, -6.491786990447023, 6.232016977803179, 25.025643012929887, 8.469894128276412, -5.697378424452704, 165.4820717201802]

totalreturns = [1]

for i in percentagechange:
    totalreturns = i / ( totalreturns * 100 )
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That still is not working for me.
I have another list
percentage change =  [6.445110695124745, 3.6760012497795813, 59.76004638390864, 45.08127797944892]
When I run the above code it comes out as
total returns =  0.43025959369031913
I know this is too low as it is saying I only have 43% of the original stake. What other link are we missing?

Comment: I'm also missing some information, maybe you could just try to do the average of all percentages, sum them all and divide the result by len(percentagechange). (Maybe this is stupid but I though that my answer was correct now I'm lost)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
import pandas as pd

percentagechange = [-2.704974336321264, -9.75579724548381, 161.1083287764476, -2.3049580623481725, -3.2221603096622586, -2.03531529638451, -6.491786990447023, 6.232016977803179, 25.025643012929887, 8.469894128276412, -5.697378424452704, 165.4820717201802]

totalreturns = 100 * (pd.Series((percentagechange))/100 + 1).cumprod().iloc[-1]

print(totalreturns)
#716.1782520447279
```

I turn the list of percentage changes into a series, divide them all by 100, add 1 and calculate the cumulative product.  By using `.iloc[-1]` I then take the last value in the series (the total percentage change).  Multiplying this by the starting value of `100`, the output is `716`.